# Problem about assigning input to a string, int array and int

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I want to take a line of input int1 int2 ... intn FUNCTIONINITIAL param1 param2. int1 to intn will store in a int array, functioninitial will contain two alpha character and param1 and param2 will store in two different int.

The problem I am facing is my code is not working for 3 or above digit number. In my following code, if my input is `11 22 33 AB 44 55`, it works fine. But if I change the input to `111 222 333 AB 444 555`, it is not working well. I know the problem is at the for loop i = i+2, but I have no idea how to make my function work with different digit numbers. Can anyone help me to fix my code?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string inputstr;
    string function;
    int arr[100] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    int para1;
    int para2;
    stringstream ss;
    getline(cin, inputstr);

    ss << inputstr;



    for(i=0;i<inputstr.length();i+= 2){
    if(isdigit(inputstr[i])){
        ss >> arr[i];
        cout<<"int: "<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }

    else if(isalpha(inputstr[i])){

        ss>>function;
        break;
    }



}
ss>>para1;
ss>>para2;
cout<<"parameter1: "<<para1<<endl;
cout<<"parameter2: "<<para2<<endl;
cout<<"function: "<<function<<endl;
}
```

Comment: your loop character per character is non consistent with the read values, see my answer for more including a proposal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were getting there and while I agree with bruno and the use of `std::vector`, using your basic-type array, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#define MAXN 100

int main (void) {

    std::string inputstr, function;
    int arr[MAXN], i, n = 0, para1, para2;
    std::stringstream ss;

    if (!getline (std::cin, inputstr)) {    /* validate read of line */
        std::cerr << "user canceled or input error.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    ss << inputstr;     /* transfer line to stringstream */

    while (n < MAXN && (ss >> arr[n]))  /* read ints until function */
        n++;
    ss.clear();         /* clear failbit */

    if (!(ss >> function)) {   /* validate read of function */
        std::cerr << "error: no function read.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(ss >> para1) || !(ss >> para2)) { /* validate read of 2 params */
        std::cerr << "error: failed to read 2 parameters.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    /* output function (para1, para2) followed by integer values */
    std::cout << '\n' << function << "(" << para1 << ", " << para2 << ")\n";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << " " << arr[i];
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Whether you use a `vector` or `int arr[]`, the approach is the same. Read `int` values storing them until your read fails on `function`. `ss.clear();` to clear `failbit` and then read `function` and `para1` and `para2`, validating the success of each and every read.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fnparams
111 222 otherFunc 333 444

otherFunc(333, 444)
 111 222
```

or

```
$ ./bin/fnparams
1 22 333 4444 55555 secretFunc 66 777

secretFunc(66, 777)
 1 22 333 4444 55555
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing

> ```
> for(i=0;i<inputstr.length();i++){
>   if(isdigit(inputstr[i])){
>     ss >> arr[i];
>     cout<<"int: "<<arr[i]<<endl;
>   }
>   else if(isalpha(inputstr[i])){
>    function += inputstr[i];
> }
> ```

Your *for* progress character per character while the read elements have more than 1 character and there are also the separators, your tests *isXXX* are not consistent with the next read element, and of course there are less elements than the number of characters in the string. To use the index *i* used for *inputstr* to put values in *arr* is wrong too, you cannot use the same index for both

For instance with the input `11 22 33 AB 44 55` :

- i=0 and `isdigit(inputstr[i])` true, you extract *11* from *ss* and you put it in `arr[0]`
- i=1 and `isdigit(inputstr[i])` true, you extract *22* from *ss* and you put it in `arr[1]`
- i=2, both `isdigit(inputstr[i])` and `isalpha(inputstr[i])` are false
- i=3 and `isdigit(inputstr[i])` true, you extract *33* from *ss* and you put it in `arr[3]`, and you did not put a value in `arr[2]` having an undefined value
- i=4 and `isdigit(inputstr[i])` true, you try to extract an *int* from *ss* but the stream refers to *AB*, nothing is extracted, the stream is on error and not clearing the error you will not be able to read something from it
- up to the end of the *for* you do nothing because the stream is on error, so *function* will not be set and will stay empty
- after the loop the stream is still on error and you will not set _param18 and *param2*, their value stay undefined

---

Just read number while you can then you will have your function then read 2 numbers again

I also recommend you to use a *std::vector* rather than an array

Example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  // read ints
  vector<int> v;
  int i;

  while (cin >> i)
    v.push_back(i);

  // not an int, is the FUNCTIONINITIAL
  string function;

  cin.clear(); // clear error
  if (! (cin >> function))
    // EOF
    return -1;

  int param1, param2;

  if (! (cin >> param1 >> param2))
    // not numbers or EOF
    return -1;

  // debug
  cout << "ints are";
  for (auto n : v)
    cout << ' ' << n;
  cout << '\n' << function << '(' << param1 << ',' << param2 << ')' << endl;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
11 22 33 AB 44 55
ints are 11 22 33
AB(44,55)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```